# Implementing Drag-to-Submit Form

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, captcha

I am sick to death of assholes spamming my site, and I hate those stupid Captcha things, and my customers have had it up to their necks with the captcha on my site.

So, I had an idea. What if there was a small line. And all they had to do was simply drag a circle from the left of the line to the right. And once the circle reaches the drop-target (end of the line), the form will then submit. Sounds simple? No need to inconveniently type some random crap just to submit a form!

See demo pic:

[image: Dragger Sample]

Does anybody know how I would implement something like this? Can someone please help me? I need a little direction.

Thank you

Comment: Interesting idea! It will require Javascript which is a downside. But it's interesting nevertheless. +1

Comment: Thank you Pekka :) I'm still looking into Javascript.

Comment: I would say that it would be easier for spammers to write a routine to fool this than it would be for a blind person to use it. Just a thought.

Comment: @dwarFish: Interesting. I'm not too sure about that though. I have a few ideas about "confirming" that it was actually a Mouse that dragged it before the form is submitted. However I'm pretty reluctant to post too many ideas on how it works, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @dwarFish: You've got me thinking now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a rather roundabout way of doing it, most spambots dont execute JavaScript in the first place, my solution would be to autofill a hidden field using javascript, or simply fill the action part of a form using javascript.